# Get custom Attribute

Tags: magento

I'm wonder how can I get custom attribute,
My custom attribute call "tim_color"
I was try get by `$_product->getAttributeText('tim_color');`

after execute I get fatal error Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object 
when I'm used

`$data['color'] = $product->getTim_color();`

in the result i'm get id, but I need the name of atrribute, how can I resolve this problem

My code of script:

```
$mage_csv = new Varien_File_Csv(); //mage CSV
$products_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();; //get products model
$products_model ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products_row = array();

foreach ($products_model as $prod)
{
    #print_r($prod);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());
    $data = array();
    $data['id_product'] = $product->getId();
    $data['color'] = $product->getTim_color();
    $data['sku'] = $product->getSku();
    $data['name'] = strip_tags($product->getName());
    $data['description'] = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($product->getDescription())));
    $data['price'] = $product->getPrice();
    $products_row[] = $data;
}
```

thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$_product->getData(’tim_color’);
```

I hope you can get the attribute value by `getAttributeText()` also. Check out,

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId()); //getting product
$_product->getAttributeText('tim_color'); //getting custom attribute value
```

Detailed discussions are [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/30879/) and [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/216409/).